# How to trace any UI control creation?

Tags: user-interface

Sometimes, some of my UI controls got created in the background thread, causing it to become unresponsive. It is a client/server desktop application.

I would like to make sure every UI control creation is marshalled up to the main thread. For that I use the IsInvokeRequired pattern.

What I would like to do now is to catch those that may still get created in a background thread and to make sure 100% that all is good. The idea is then to globally add some tracings on any UI components creation that would help us identify the current thread. Is there events that are triggered during (before/after) UI component creation that I can handle and where I could put my traces ? I have controls like treeviews, listviews ... in my UI.
Or is there any other ways to achieve the same goal ?

Thanks.